# Redmine API - Creating Issues

Tags: redmine, redmine-api

I am trying to use Redmine's API to create issues, but it doesn't seem to let me specify who is submitting the ticket. I have tried getting `author_id` and it doesn't seem to work.

This is what the JSON data in the POST looks like:

```
    {
        "issue": {
            "author_id": 3,
            "project_id": 26,
            "subject": "Q-12345678",
            "description": "This is a test"
        }
    }
```

The issue is being created, but the author is being set to anonymous. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I figured it out. As it turns out `author_id` is not set as a "safe parameter".

I opened up `app/models/issue.rb` and added `author_id` on line 337.

So now that block of code looks like this:

```
    safe_attributes 'tracker_id',
      'status_id',
      'category_id',
      'author_id',
      'assigned_to_id',
      'priority_id',
      'fixed_version_id',
      'subject',
      'description',
      'start_date',
      'due_date',
      'done_ratio',
      'estimated_hours',
      'custom_field_values',
      'custom_fields',
      'lock_version',
      'notes',
      :if => lambda {|issue, user| issue.new_record? || user.allowed_to?(:edit_issues, issue.project) }
```

**EDIT**

I think this might be a better solution in `app/models/issue.rb` (line 375)

After

```
    safe_attributes 'parent_issue_id',
        :if => lambda {|issue, user| (issue.new_record? || user.allowed_to?(:edit_issues, issue.project)) &&
          user.allowed_to?(:manage_subtasks, issue.project)}
```

I added

```
    safe_attributes 'author_id',
        :if => lambda {|issue, user| issue.new_record? || user.allowed_to?(:admin, issue.project)}
```